# StandardSetController.getListViewOptions() only returning "All"

Tags: apex, standardsetcontroller

I have a VF page tied to a controller which utilizes "StandardSetController" to retrieve the list of views created. The problem is whenever I am trying to get those list views using `getListViewOptions()` on runtime, it only returns one list view which is "All". When executed independently (through console), the same code works just as expected.

Here is some snippet of my code:

VF page

```
<apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1">
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange"
    rerender="mpb,commandLinksPagination" action="{!resetFilter}"
    status="idStatus" />
<apex:selectOptions value="{!listViewOptions}" />
```

Controller

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController con {
    get {

        if(con == null) {
            List<EUR_CRM_Account__c> accList = new List<EUR_CRM_Account__c>();

            con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                'select name, EUR_CRM_Group_Outlet_Type__c, EUR_CRM_Outlet_Type__c,EUR_CRM_Outlet_Type__r.EUR_CRM_name__c,  EUR_CRM_City__c ,EUR_CRM_Image_Level_Name__c ,EUR_CRM_Group_Outlet_Type_Name__c ' +
                ', EUR_CRM_No_of_Active_Contracts__c, ownerid, owner.name, recordTypeId, EUR_CRM_Company_Establishment__c '  + 
                'from EUR_CRM_Account__c LIMIT 1'
            ));                


            System.debug(con.getListViewOptions()); // "All" is printed

            if(filterId != null) {

                this.con.setPageSize(pSize);
                con.setFilterId(filterId);
                this.euAccounts = null;
                this.selectedAccounts = new Set<Id>();
            }
        }

        return con;
    }
    set;
}

public SelectOption[] getListViewOptions() {
    List<SelectOption> selOpList = new List<SelectOption>();
    selOpList.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    selOpList.addAll(con.getListViewOptions());

    return selOpList;
}
```

Any feedback/guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Does your page have an id parameter?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. My VF page is tied to a button so the Id parameter is inserted by default. Had to change the button binding from VF page to custom URL in order for it to work.

Comment: Glad my experience helped you out. :) I voted you up btw.